# SQL count distinct output not as wished

Tags: sql, sqlite

%%sql

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.email) CountRockListeners
     
FROM
    customer c
         JOIN invoice i ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
         JOIN invoice_line il ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id
         JOIN track t ON il.track_id = t.track_id
         JOIN genre g ON t.genre_Id = g.genre_Id
WHERE g.name = 'Rock' OR g.name = 'Pop'
```

I have this SQL code and want to return count of Rock and Pop listeners, but it only returns the count of Rock which is 59 .Pop is 32.
So I want it to return 59+32
Please advise?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (no images.) Simplify, [mcve].

Comment: Those Rock listeners probably listen to Pop, too. Add `g.name` to Group By and Select.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.email) as cnt_either
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN g.name = 'Rock' THEN c.email END) as cnt_rock,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN g.name = 'Pop' THEN c.email END) as cnt_pop
FROM customer c JOIN
     invoice i
     ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id JOIN
     invoice_line il
     ON i.invoice_id = il.invoice_id JOIN
     track t
     ON il.track_id = t.track_id JOIN
     genre g
     ON t.genre_Id = g.genre_Id
WHERE g.name IN ('Rock', 'Pop')
```